# Keep cleos wallet unlocked using --unlock-timeout arg

Tags: cleos, wallet, keosd

I'm trying to keep my eos wallet unlocked. I'm using the cleos command, but I see that there is a **--unlock-timeout arg** option for the keosd command, but how do I use it for cleos? I'm connecting to a remote node.

Answer (score 1):

Launch keosd manually and use cleos option --no-auto-keosd.